# How can I collect the ID's of Facebook users who like a 'post' in my fan page?

Tags: facebook

I just finished a Facebook contest event and want to invite all visitors to see the results.

It will be much simpler if I can configure the Facebook page to only accept users who 'fan', 'like', or 'comment' on a post on my fan page.

Is there any way to collect all the Facebook users who have 'liked' or 'commented' the related 'post' on my Facebook fan page?

Answer (score 3):

lucemia: You can query the user id's of the user who liked your post from facebook using fql.

the following link will help you

[Link to FB Like table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/)

This will solve your issues I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKt6AUMOC-Q

I'm not sure if it's the ideal answer for you.

I recommend using Facebook insights. It provides a lot of statistical information and is a little bit like Google Analytics.

http://www.facebook.com/insights
http://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=insights